# this pointer as a const pointer

Tags: c++, oop, this

I read that the `this` pointer is a `const pointer` (which sounds perfectly logical) which can let us change the object it is pointing to but can't change the address it holds. But when I do this:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
    int val;

    public:
    class A* fun()
    {
        return this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    class A objA;
    class A objB;
    *(objA.fun())=objB;

    return 0;
}
```

Even though the pointer returned holds the address of `objA`, it easily holds the address of `objB`. How is it possible as similar code for simple variable fails:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int *const p=&i;

    p=&i;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The meaning of `this` is still unchanged in your example. It still points to the object it pointed to at the beginning of the scope

Comment: **Do not** write `class T` when *using* the type, use this syntax only when declaring the class. The only reason why this is even valid is for compatibility with C (by analogy with `struct T`), but *it has no effect*, it is highly non-idiomatic, and it is clutter.

Answer (score 8):

```
objA.fun()
```

evaluates to the address of `objA` (in other words, it's `&objA`). So what you're doing is:

```
*(&objA) = objB;
```

which is equivalent to:

```
objA = objB;
```

So you're just copying `objB` into `objA`.

Answer (score 4):

Your question implies that the following changes the address of `A`:

```
*(objA.fun())=objB;
```

Quite simply, it does not.

You're dereferencing a copy of `objA`'s `this` pointer and assigning to that.  Put another way, all the above does is call `objA.operator=(objB)`.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't assigning to `this` at all here. Instead you are using the value of `this` in an expression that includes an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are 2 things in play here. For one thing, `fun()` does not return `this` by reference. It passes it by value.

This means that something like this code snippet:

```
objA.fun()=&objB;
```

will not change the value of `this`. `objA.fun()` returns a copy of the address stored in `this`, not a reference to `this` itself. That means we can't change `this` itself with this code, even if we wanted to.

To be able to change `this` itself, you'd need to pass `this` by reference, which would look something like this:

```
A* const& fun()
    {
        return this;
    }
```

Now, this snippet:

```
objA.fun()=&objB;
```

will fail to compile like you'd expect it would, as it is roughly equivalent to the other code you posted.

Secondly, there is also something else in play here that makes your first code different from your second. That is that you are dereferencing the pointer. What you are doing is this instead:

```
*(objA.fun())=objB;
```

That is not the same as your other code for one reason: the `*`. The `*` operator dereferences the pointer, meaning that you are now referring to the **contents** of the pointer, not the pointer itself. That means you are doing this instead:

```
int main()
{
    int i;
    int i2 = 42;
    int *const p=&i;

    *p=i2;
    return 0;
}
```

That is not the same thing. In this example, you are changing the value stored in `p`, but you are not changing `p`. Your original code is roughly equivalent to this, which is why it compiles.